# How do I compare non integer numbers using freemarker templete

Tags: numbers, freemarker

I use freemarker template in my Java application to load my pages in my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`. Usually, I use built-ins like `gt, lt, lte, gte` etc to compare two numbers. 
Currently I have a situation where there value returned from the controller is a `double`. Now I have values such as `-1.0` or `0.0`. All I am trying to do is check if the value is less than `0` or equal to `0` so that I can conditionally display my contents as I always do.

Is there any way to compare numbers in freemarker when the number is `double`. I could not find any suitable solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Freemarker doesn't really treat doubles differently than integers. This is from [Apache Freemarker Docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_datamodel_types.html#dgui_datamodel_scalar):

`Number: For example the price of a product. Whole numbers and non-whole numbers are not distinguished; there is only a single number type. So for example 3/2 will be always 1.5, and never 1. Just like if you are using a calculator.`

I have used this and other similar instances in my templates with no issues where `salesTaxRate` is a `double` in java:

```
<#if (orderSummary.order.ioItems[0].salesTaxRate > 0)>          
    <td>Tax (${orderSummary.order.ioItems[0].salesTaxRate}%):</td>
<#else>         
    <td>Tax:</td>
</#if>
```

What is happening when you try the comparison?  Are you running into issues where the value is supposed to be zero but is actually some insignificant value (0.000000000001)?